# Why is there a right margin line in Android Studio editor window?

Tags: android-studio

There is a vertical line in the middle of the file editor window in Android Studio. I'm unable to change the margin line. Below is the screenshot of the right margin line:

[image]

Where is the setting to change this line?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I guess you mean this line?

[image]

That's a ruler for the max column width.

You can change the max column width from:
**File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Right Margin (columns)**

[image]

Comment: yes!that's it,but why it change to this?i haven't modified the style before

Comment: It might be required to go to `Code Style->your_language->Wrapping and Braces->Hard wrap at: <some_value>`

Comment: For mac : Preferences>Editor>Code style>[your_language]>Line length

Comment: Is there any option to change the color of that line?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Dart language:

**settings -> Code Style -> Dart**

and set **Line length** to your preference.

Answer (score 3):

**To disable In Android Studio 4.**

> File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > "Select the programing languae"** > Line length

Set it to: 300 for example.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8TW3.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

For the new Android Studio the location is: **Editor** > **Code Style** > **Hard wrap at**.
The standard value is 100, just change to 0

Answer (score 0):

That line historically represents the margin of A4 paper, that is useful only if you need to print the code. Old school says that you should keep your code inside that margin, to guarantee much portability.

But.. nowadays in the real life it makes no sense, because we always use advanced editors, bigger displays, and I never have to print any single line of code..

To remove the line in the latest Android Studio version `Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1` ,

> File->Settings->Editor->General->Show hard wrap guide

or just search hard wrap in settings window and uncheck the `Foreground` and click apply.

[image]