# Strange vertical line appear in my Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I was working normally with my Android Studio. Normally, I use my real phone to run the app, but today I use the virtual device in Android Studio. When I hide the device manager tab, it shows a strange vertical line in my coding space, which is very annoying to me.
Please see the photo, you can see the line cutting the "String phone".

[image]

Comment: check this answer and try solution your problem by it https://stackoverflow.com/a/72709232/11654799

Comment: Setting 'Hard wrap at' to 0 should eliminate it or uncheck 'Show hard wrap and visual guides' in Editor | General | Appearance - can also search in 'Settings' for "hard wrap".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the vertical line in the android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708463/how-to-remove-the-vertical-line-in-the-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

If the line is at column 80 or 100 or something like this, it is most probably a visual guideline for code width. There should be some option in the settings to either deactivate it or specify the column at which it should be displayed.

Edit: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24558830) that shows how to set the code margin and other options.